# Resolve RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Tags: python, recursion, karatsuba

I'm not getting what is wrong in my code. How should I fix this recursion error in Karatsuba multiplication?

```
def karatsuba(x,y):
    if len(str(x))==1 or len(str(y))==1:
        return int(x)*int(y)
    else:
        n=max(len(str(x)),len(str(y)))
        nby2=n//2
        a=x/(10**nby2)
        b=x%(10**nby2)
        c=y/(10**nby2)
        d=y%(10**nby2)
        ac=karatsuba(a,c)
        bd=karatsuba(b,d)
        k=karatsuba(a+b,c+d)-ac-bd
        p=((10**2*nby2)*ac+((10**(nby2))*k)+bd)
        return p
```

Error messages-

```
line 11, in karatsuba
    ac=karatsuba(a,c)
  [Previous line repeated 989 more times]

 line 2, in karatsuba
    if len(str(x))==1 or len(str(y))==1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Comment: A first comment unrelated to the error: when is `len(str(x))==1`? When `x<10`... And why take `int(x)` if `x` is an integer?

Comment: Add a `print(x,y)` as the first statement of your function and you will see the issue.

Comment: Note also that `10**2*nby2` is not `10**(2*nby2)` but `(10**2)*nby2`. And given that you write `//` for one of the divisions, I expect `x/(10**nby2)` to be a float.

Answer (score 0):

`x/(10**nby2)` returns float so it has to be `x//(10**nby2)`.
Also change `(10**2*nby2)` to `(10**(2*nby2)`

```
def karatsuba(x,y):
    if len(str(x))==1 or len(str(y))==1:
        return int(x)*int(y)
    else:
        n=max(len(str(x)),len(str(y)))
        nby2=n//2
        a=x//(10**nby2)
        b=x%(10**nby2)
        c=y//(10**nby2)
        d=y%(10**nby2)
        ac=karatsuba(a,c)
        bd=karatsuba(b,d)
        k=karatsuba(a+b,c+d)-ac-bd
        p=((10**(2*nby2))*ac+((10**(nby2))*k)+bd)
        return p
```